# scaling bitmaps to fit 854 wide screen

Tags: android, scale, screen-resolution

I'm starting to put together a game but am getting a little confused with the screen resolutions and density stuff.

I have an image that is 800 pixels wide and has been added to the drawable mdpi folder.
It gets drawn ok, but on a 854 pixel wide screen, there's a 54 pixel gap.

What's the best way to make the image fit the screen?

thanks

Comment: could you specify what programming language / context this is in?

Comment: @Mikey - Google says its for android

Answer (score 0):

Add the follwing class to your project and change your layout like this

**View**

```
<my.package.name.AspectRatioImageView
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/my_image"
    android:id="@+id/my_image"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

**Class**

```
package my.package.name;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * ImageView which scales an image while maintaining
 * the original image aspect ratio
 *
 */
public class AspectRatioImageView extends ImageView {

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param Context context
     */
    public AspectRatioImageView(Context context) {

        super(context);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param Context context
     * @param AttributeSet attrs
     */
    public AspectRatioImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(context, attrs);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param Context context
     * @param AttributeSet attrs
     * @param int defStyle
     */
    public AspectRatioImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    /**
     * Called from the view renderer.
     * Scales the image according to its aspect ratio.
     */
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = width * getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight() / getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
}
```